# Representing and Visualising Concrete Groups

Tags: group-theory, visualization

What are some interesting and attractive ways to visualise specific Groups?
Like: The Rubik's Cube, A set of Permutation Matrices, And.. What else?

Comment: Cayley graphs come to mind, for one.

Comment: Symmetry groups of geometric objects are easy to visualize by staring at the geometry. Examples include symmetry groups of regular planar polygons (finite dihedral groups), and symmetry groups of the five Platonic solids.